# Fastest way to convert a textual integer representation of bits to actual bits?

Tags: swift, math, integer, bit

For example, I am textually representing an 8-bit integer's bits as `10010111`, (*also an integer*, but expressed as text in my source code file).

Given the size beforehand (in order to account for prefixed zeroes), what is the fastest way to convert a textual integer representation of bytes to the actual bits it represents? I'd rather not convert it into a `String` and iterate through that, I'm sure there must be some mathematical trick to it.

`10010111` is translated to `-105`, an `Int8`.

**I do not want conversions using literals. The value of my integer is not known at compile time.**

Comment: What kind of "textual representation" is *not* a string?

Comment: `10010111` is an integer, but when I'm writing code in my IDE it is expressed in text. I want to be able to convert this 'textual integer representation' (emphasis being on integer) to the data it represents. Perhaps you can suggest an edit to make this clearer in my question?

Comment: It is frustrating.  I almost suggested taking the log base 10, then raising 2 to the power of the result.  Doesn't work.  Spektre's approach is the best I know of.  Or if you want to process the number as an integer without converting to a char array, you could process the thing by taking modulo 10 to get the least significant digit, divide by 10 to right shift 1 decimal place.  I don't think that would be even nearly as fast as using a char array though.

Comment: But either way, it seems a person is stuck processing these conversions one place value at a time.

Comment: That is sad. I already knew about @Spektre's, which in fact is my current approach, however I was looking for something faster.

Comment: If you put `0b` (zero b) in front of your values they will be treated as binary:  `let arr: [UInt8] = [0b10010111, 0b00000001, 0b11111111]`

Comment: `let num = Int8(bitPattern: 0b10010111)`

Comment: @vacawama: This works only with literals. What if I want to do this at runtime?

Comment: I thought you might be representing your values as literals in your code and wanted a way to represent binary values.  How does a value such as 10010111 get into your variable in the first place?

Comment: @vacawama: "What does your app even do" is not relevant to the question or it's answers.

Comment: I don't care if your app is a game or a calculator.  I want to know if you're reading the data from a file or reading it from user input (stdin) or you just have an array of literals that you want converted.

Comment: @vacawama: It could be any of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
let num = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8("10010111", radix: 2)!)
print(num) // -105
```

Or, if the "representation" is assigned to an integer:

```
let input = 10010111
let num = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(String(input), radix: 2)!)
print(num) // -105
```

This uses an intermediate string representation, but you don't have
to "manually" iterate over it.

Of course, both methods will crash if there are invalid binary
digits or an overflow, so you should use optional binding instead.

The conversion can also be done with pure integer arithmetic
and bit shifting, without using strings:

```
var input = 10010111

var num : Int8 = 0
var mask : Int8 = 1
while input > 0 {
    if input % 10 != 0 {
        num |= mask
    }
    mask <<= 1
    input /= 10
}
print(num) // -105
```

I leave it up to you to measure which method is faster :)

If the input is restricted to 8 bits then the fastest method would
probably be to define a dictionary

```
let dict : [ Int : Int8 ] = [ 0: 0, 1: 1, 10: 2, 11: 3, 100: 4, ...]
```

with 256 entries, so that each conversion is just a single
dictionary lookup. For larger numbers the conversion can then be
done in 8-bit chunks.

Comment: This _is_ my current approach, however I was quite hoping to avoid the string intermediate.

Comment: @VatsalManot: It would have been helpful if you had shown your current approach in the question :) – Do you think it is a performance issue? Have you measured it?

Comment: This is currently not a performance issue, but I was curious as to whether a faster approach existed.

Comment: @VatsalManot: Better in what aspect? Faster code, shorter code, ...?

Comment: I was just editing my comment to address that! Talk about coincidence.

Comment: @VatsalManot: I have added a "string-free" conversion method. But I haven't measured if that is faster or not.

Comment: I'll test it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit2]**

1. create table with decadic representation of each possible nibel (4bit chunk)

   - `tab[16]= { 0,1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111 };`
   - if you want to process by different bit size then change the size of table accordingly
2. now process all nibels

   - extract each nibel from the LSB to MSB
   - and add its value in decadic to output value
   - `for (out=0,b=1;in;in>>=4,b*=10000) out+=tab[in&15]*b;`
   - `out` is output value
   - `in` is input value
   - `b` is weight of nibel `{ 1,10000,100000000,... }`
   - `>>=` is bit shift right to the same variable
   - `+=` add to the same variable
   - `in&15` is logical `AND` leaving only lowest 4 bits of `in`

Comment: No. I have a number, and I want another number with the bits that which my first number textually represents.

Comment: ow that is entirely different question ... something like BCD but in binary I see

Comment: Eheheheh, I think you missed the 'Swift' tag :p

Comment: @VatsalManot why? algorithm has not much to do with language if I show you how in C++ with enough text about how you should be able to port it to your platform ...As I am not familiar with SWIFT I can not code in it directly. Others may and their answer will be better but I see just one answer and it uses string conversion you want to avoid.  If you wait a bit I will try to code this conversion in C++ (have to test it first)

Comment: If you want to answer in a language independent form, then use pseudocode. If I'm not familiar with the language you're programming it, it might as well be Greek. For the record, I do know C and a bit of C++, however it does not change the fact that you should have used pseudocode/Swift.

Comment: @VatsalManot removed unrelevant code and text added edit2 with the desired conversion using conversion `table` for speed up

Comment: Thanks, your time is much appreciated. Although I've accepted @MartinR's answer, your answer has been considered as well.

Comment: @VatsalManot you need to find compromise between speed and memory size of the `tab` try to enlarge it until it stops speeding up the process ... if you have just 8 bit numbers you can use `tab[256]` unless you are on memory lacking system like MCU but if you got 1024 bit numbers ... too big table will not fit into CACHE and too small `tab` will slowing down the process a bit